# angularjs link between routes

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have set up a route as follows in my AngularJS app.

```
audit.config(["$routeProvider",function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
    .when('/AuditData/:auditCode', {
        templateUrl: 'templ/AuditData.html',
        controller: 'AuditDataController'
    })
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templ/AuditSelect.html',
        controller: 'AuditSelectController'
    })
    .when('/AuditSetup', {
        templateUrl: 'templ/AuditSetup.html',
        controller: 'AuditSetupController'
    }}]);
```

The routing works as expected. The user is shown a list of audit codes in `AuditSelect` that are loaded from a REST service. Each item in the list is to be a link to the data associated with that code, i.e.: `#/AuditData/:auditCode`, `<a href="#/AuditData/code123">`.

(templ/AuditSelect.html):

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Audit Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="auditCode in auditCodes">
            <td><a href="#/AuditData/{{auditCode.auditCode}}"> {{auditCode.auditCode}}</a></td>
            <td>{{auditCode.description}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My problem is that when the users clicks on the link, they are taken back to `'/'` and not `'/AuditData/:auditCode'`.

Update:
I found what was wrong :-) I was missing a bang in the href in my template. I've also switched to using ng-href (which didn't work without the bang either, but does with it)

`<td><a ng-href="#!/AuditData/{{auditCode.auditCode}}">{{auditCode.auditCode}}</a></td>`

Comment: Can you print the values of `auditCode.auditCode`?

Comment: Yes, the values of auditCode.auditCode appear e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8080/client/audit/#/AuditData/auditCode3

Comment: What I've now done instead is add a method to the AuditSelectController `<td><a ng-click="selectData(auditCode.auditCode)">{{auditCode.auditCode}}</a></td>` which changes the path in $location `$location.path('AuditData/auditCode3 ')` . This works and $routeParams makes the auditCode available in the AuditDataController. It doesn't seem to be the ideal way of doing it, but I can't find why my original approach wasn't working.